# Two observers Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have Two observers and in each observer I change the value of the property of the other observer. In this case I dont want that the other observer will execute. 
How Can I change that The observer will execute only in change of the property from outside?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use a local variable to stop the update.

```
Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    properties: {
        myProperty: {
            type: String,
            observer: '_myObserverA'
        }
    },
    observers: [
        '_myObserverB(myProperty)'
    ],
    _myObserverA(newValue) {
        if(!this._localUpdate) {
            //do stuff here
        } else {
            this._localUpdate = false;
        }
    },
    _myObserverB(newValue) {
        this._localUpdate = true;
        //do stuff here
    }
})
```

Comment: But they will be different cause I realy change them

Answer (score 1):

You must use an observer like that:

```
Polymer({

  is: 'x-custom',

  properties: {
    preload: Boolean,
    src: String,
    size: String
  },

  observers: [
    'updateImage(preload, src, size)'
  ],

  updateImage: function(preload, src, size) {
    // ... do work using dependent values
  }

});
```

More info in: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#multi-property-observers

Comment: I dont understand how this solve the problem. what is the difference between the regular way to this way? how does it solve the racing condition?
I want 2 observer 1 to to each value.

Comment: I dont want that one observer will cause to the another observer to work

Comment: This way you will monitor all properties at once. If any one (or event all of them) changes, it will call handler only once.

Comment: Oh, I see. I hadn't understand that, sorry. So using a flag to prevent the observer method apply its behavior, like @Srik proposed, will get things working.